# How to extract path params from Django Request object?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on my own role-based authorization decorator for Django and did write some `validation` classes to be used for each role.

My validation classes currently are receiving, as arguments, the `request` object, and the `view` itself.

But for some roles, I need to extract a `client_id` from my URL to verify some rules.

How can I extract this as a key-value pair from the `Request` object?

I know that Django injects the path params as key-value pairs using keyword arguments but how could I extract this from the request?

Answer (score 4):

You can obtain the positional and named parameters of a request with [**`.resolver_match`** attribute <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.resolver_match) and then use the [**`.args`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.ResolverMatch.args) or [**`.kwargs`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.ResolverMatch.kwargs) of the `ResolverMatch`:

```
request.resolver_match.args    # positional parameters (tuple)
request.resolver_match.kwargs  # named parameters (dictionary)
```

If you thus want to access the value for `client_id`, you do so with:

```
request.resolver_match.kwargs['client_id']
```